# How do I determine whether a deadlock will occur in this system?

Tags: deadlock, bankers-algorithm

N processes share M resource units that can be reserved and release only one at a time.  The maximum need of each process does not exceed M, and the sum of all maximum needs is less than M+N.  Can a deadlock occur in the system ?

Comment: Sounds like homework. For which the usual answer applies: 42

Comment: Get this: in SO, one can HELP you cope with your homework. But asking to actually do it for you is just rude

Answer (score 1):

I hope you got the answer. Answering this question for other visitors.

The answer is that the **deadlock will not occur** in the system.

The proof is given in the image below.

The image was taken from http://alumni.cs.ucr.edu/~choua/school/cs153/Solution%20Manual.pdf on page 31

Answer (score 0):

the system you are describing looks like [semaphores](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29)

about your last question : YES. You "could" always do a deadlock ; if you don't see how, ask a young/shameful/motivated/deviant developer.

One good way to make a good one ; is to have strange locking/releasing resources rules. For example, if a process needs M resources to perform a task, he could locks half of them right away, and then waits for the other half to be available before doing anything.

I assume he never gives up until he have its M precious resources and releases them all once the task done.

A single process wouldn't cause much problems but several will as they will lock more than M total resources and will need more of them to get out this frozen state.